# Can I affirm this function is bijective?

Tags: functions

Given a set A, $f(x)$ is a bijection, $g(x)$ is a bijection and $h(x)$ like this:

$h(x) = f(x)$ if $x$ is in A

$h(x) = g(x)$ if $x$ is not in A

Can I conclude that $h(x)$ is a bijection?

Comment: Where are your functions going? Are them in an upper set $B$ containing $A$?

Comment: This is not clear.  I guess $f,g,h$ are functions, yes?  Between what sets?

Comment: I'll edit the question